# Django Redis Error unknown command 'BZPOPMIN'

Tags: python, django, redis

I've installed `Redis 3.0.54`.
Django is updated.
I'm learning channels from the [tutorial page](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html).

This is my terminal window for redis-cli and redis server
[Image of Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh6RK.jpg)

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 06, 2020 - 16:04:58
Django version 3.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.4.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
HTTP GET /chat/lobby/ 200 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:60841]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:60843]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:60843]
Exception inside application: ERR unknown command 'BZPOPMIN'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Envs\py2\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 183, in __call__
    return await self.inner(receive, self.send)
  File "C:\Users\\Envs\py2\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 41, in coroutine_call
    await inner_instance(receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\\Envs\py2\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
    [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
  File "C:\Users\\Envs\py2\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 58, in await_many_dispatch
    await task
  File "C:\Users\\Envs\py2\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 50, in await_many_dispatch
    result = task.result()
  File "C:\Users\\Envs\py2\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 453, in receive
    real_channel
  File "C:\Users\\Envs\py2\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 508, in receive_single
    index, channel_key, timeout=self.brpop_timeout
  File "C:\Users\\Envs\py2\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 345, in _brpop_with_clean
    result = await connection.bzpopmin(channel, timeout=timeout)
aioredis.errors.ReplyError: ERR unknown command 'BZPOPMIN'
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:60843]
```

Answer (score 7):

[BZPOPMIN](https://redis.io/commands/bzpopmin) and [BZPOPMAX](https://redis.io/commands/bzpopmax)(also non-blocking versions `ZPOPMIN` and `ZPOPMAX`) are "Available since 5.0.0". You need to upgrade your redis to at least version 5 to use them, since you use version 3.0.54.

You may check [download page](https://redis.io/download) for available versions and instructions to download them.

Answer (score 4):

download the latest version of Redis from here and try it will work

https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases